# How to pass in this function in order to decode the HTML?

Tags: javascript

How can I pass unsescapeHTML() into useApiData() in order to replace the characters that are being encoded?

```
function unescapeHtml(data) {
    return data.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
        .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
        .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
        .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}

function useApiData(data) {
document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = `${data[0].question}`
document.querySelector("#answer1").innerHTML = data[0].correct_answer
document.querySelector("#answer2").innerHTML = data[0].incorrect_answers[0]
document.querySelector("#answer3").innerHTML = data[0].incorrect_answers[1]
document.querySelector("#answer4").innerHTML = data[0].incorrect_answers[2]
}
```

Comment: I am using the Open Trivia Database API and some of the punctuation is encoded. I tried to follow the documentation, but the suggestions do not help. https://opentdb.com/api_config.php

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. What prevents you from using `unescapeHtml(data[0].correct_answer)` inside `useApiData`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the replacements are needed in `data`, you can pass the function as an argument and call it by reference:

```
function unescapeHtml(data) {
  return data.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
    .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
    .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
    .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
    .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}

function useApiData(data, formatFn) {
  document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = formatFn(data[0].question)
  document.querySelector("#answer1").innerHTML = formatFn(data[0].correct_answer))
  document.querySelector("#answer2").innerHTML = formatFn(data[0].incorrect_answers[0])
  document.querySelector("#answer3").innerHTML = formatFn(data[0].incorrect_answers[1])
  document.querySelector("#answer4").innerHTML = formatFn(data[0].incorrect_answers[2])
}

useApiData(data, unescapeHtml)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to remove the base64 encoding that was coming in from the API. I thought replacing the character was the answer, but I needed to remove the encoding using atob()

```
function removeBase64Encoding(answer) {
    const newAnswer = {
        category: window.atob(answer.category),
        correct_answer: window.atob(answer.correct_answer),
        difficulty: window.atob(answer.difficulty),
        question: window.atob(answer.question),
        type: window.atob(answer.type),
        incorrect_answers: answer.incorrect_answers.map(window.atob)
    }
    return newAnswer
}
```